# How can I make SlickGrid right to left?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I'm using `SlickGrid` but I want to using it with the Arabic language which requires the direction be from right to left.

```
columns[0]={'id':'title', 'name':'Title', 'field':'title', 'width': 10, 'sortable': true};
columns[1]={'id':'name', 'name':'Name', 'field':'name', 'width': 10, 'sortable': true};

var grid, data = [],
options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: true,
    autoHeight: true
}, numberOfItems = 5, items = [], indices=[], isAsc = true, currentSortCol = { id: "title" };    
grid = new Slick.Grid("#container", data, columns, options);
```

For Example see image:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbmaY.png

How can I achieve this with SlickGrid?

Comment: What exactly do you want to be rtl? Do you want the columns in a different order?

Comment: I want to make grid beginning from right side (reflect grid) i.e(first grid column beginning from right, horizontal scroll bar beginning from right side). yes like rtl in Html

Comment: Surely I am missing something, but why not just pass the column and data arrays in the reverse order?

Comment: @vemv Right to Left languages requires reading words from right to left.

Comment: sry, still don't really understand the problem. I've done rtl apps before and as soon as you use an rtl font the browser renders the text from right-to-left automatically (under Windows at least).

Comment: @njreed when you make application for rtl languages you must reflect every thing because user reading scope is rtl.
e.g: if there is a horizontal scroll bar scrolling will be rtl.
and windows reflect everything when using Arabic windows version.

Comment: Please update your question to leave clear which elements should be displayed rtl.

Comment: @os ip: I realise that, but I've always let the OS/browser handle that automatically. I presume you're using the DIR attribute of course. Maybe you could post a couple of images. Unfortunately I don't have Arabic Windows to test on (not on that project any more)

Comment: @os ip: I Looked at the image but I can't see what you're asking for. The image looks ok to me. The columns are rendered in the reverse order and the arabic text renders rtl (although I can't read the arabic text). What exactly is wrong with the result?

Comment: @njreed the first image is example for what i need, SlickGrid beginning from right side instead of left, Horizontal scroll bar beginning from right side instead of left, vertical scroll bar on the left side instead of right, when i resize column to left the column size from right will be smaller instead of larger. i.e reflect every thing.

Comment: @os ip: I presume you're using a DIR attribute in your code? Assuming so, can you post an image of how the slickgrid renders and tell us what is wrong with it.

Comment: @os ip: See my answer below. Out of curiosity I tried it in jsFiddle myself and I see the problem now.

Comment: @osip did you solve this issue? if so, please post your solution as an answer. I am facing the same problem now

Answer (score -1):

I thought this would work using the built-in RTL rendering in the browser to render the markup right-to-left.

HTML

```
<div dir="rtl" id="myGrid" style="width:400px;height:150px;">    
</div>
```

Javascript

```
columns.reverse();
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/J93Mz/)

As you can see in the fiddle, the div renders RTL as one would expect but there seems to be a problem with the rendering of the column headers. I haven't dug into the code but maybe there is some absolute positioning or other trickery that conflicts with the RTL setting. No idea how many other features could cause problems (cell editors, formatters, etc.)

Comment: Basically when i tried direction="rtl", I had same unexpected result of headers. Many Thanks.